# Google Fusion Tables Map - mouseover

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Regarding to Google Fusion Tables Map with Mouse Over, exactly this
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles

How can I get this map but for a specific country, for example for "Spain" only.

I want to see the cities of Spain in the map only, not the world wide countries.

Comment: Look at importing KML files for Spain.  One source is: http://www.gadm.org/, [here is what the adm3 level looks like (using the KMZ, not FusionTables)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/ESP_adm3_kmz.zip) (not sure what level you are interested in, you also have to worry about the size of the dataset vs. the limitations on FusionTables)

Comment: @geocodezip I downloaded the adm3 of my country, now how can I link it with fusion tables? I want the maps to change color on mousehover

Comment: You have to import it into a FusionTable, then use the code you reference to activate mouse overs.